# Command line options in Filezilla

Tags: command-line, ftp, filezilla

How do I invoke Filezilla from the command line to upload the contents of a directory? I would also like to set parameters like overwrite all etc.

From [help page](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_%28Client%29) all I see is options for opening Filezilla with specific server etc, but not to upload...

Answer (score 2):

Consider using something like [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) or [NcFTP](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/), designed for command-line use.

Comment: FileZilla is awesome!!.. multithreded and resumable.. they have covered a lot of annonying edge cases

Comment: FileZilla is a great program, but a standard FTP through the command line or through Cygwin will give you what you want.  You can open multiple windows to do more work.